# Populate cells in Excel with text from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, ms-office

I have a table in Excel with data

```
Type, Reason
===============
1, Some text
1, Other text
2, More text
2, Even more text
```

What I want is to extract the reasons based on the type. So in another sheet in my workbook, I want to select the type with a single cell, and then get the list of reasons (without any empty cells/rows).

I guess I would need `=INDEX()` to select the row numbers, but I don't know how to filter, so I only get those with e.g. type=2.

I know it is easy in VBA, but is it also possible with standard functions?

Comment: Is the desired output to have `More text` and `Even more text` concatenated in a single cell?

Comment: Nope. I just want to extract all the strings. So it would be equivalent of doing something like `SELECT Reason FROM table WHERE Type = 1` and then get all the strings. But I want to do it with pure Excel formulas